# Behavior of a sum on the boundary of convergence/divergence

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, summation, asymptotics, divergent-series

I am seeking the behavior of the sum
$$
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln\left(n\right)}{n}\,z^{n}
$$

as $z \to 1^{-}$.  I know that at $z = 1$, it diverges.  So, ideally, I would like to know how it behaves as a function of $z$ in a left neighborhood of $1$.  I thought that in some way it may be related to the Polylogarithm function, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Related: [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/726692/5531) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/732361/5531).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here are some notes [PDF]](https://mathstat.dal.ca/~antoniov/boundaryasymp.pdf) on this topic. The basic idea is to compare the sum to the corresponding integral, which is often easier to estimate.

Lemma 3 of those notes:

> For a given function $\psi : [N,\infty) \to \mathbb R^+$ suppose that the map $t \mapsto \psi(t) x^t$ is unimodal with maximum at $t = t_x \geq N$, $0 < x < 1$.  Then
>   $$
> \sum_{n \geq N} \psi(n) x^n = \int_N^\infty \psi(t) x^t\,dt + O\left(\psi(t_x)x^{t_x}\right) + O(1)
> $$
>   as $x \to 1^-$.

The map $t \mapsto \frac{\log t}{t} x^t$ is indeed unimodal, and $\frac{\log t}{t} x^t \leq 1/e$ for all $0 \leq x  \leq 1$. Thus

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\log n}{n} x^n = \int_1^\infty \frac{\log t}{t} x^t\,dt + O(1) \tag{$*$}
$$

as $x \to 1^-$. If we set $\lambda = -1/\log x$ (so that $\lambda \to \infty$ as $x \to 1^-$) and make the substitution $s = t/\lambda$, the integral becomes

$$
\begin{align}
\int_1^\infty \frac{\log t}{t} x^t\,dt &= \int_1^\infty \frac{\log t}{t} e^{-t/\lambda}\,dt \\
&= \log \lambda \int_{1/\lambda}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-s}}{s}\,ds + \int_{1/\lambda}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-s} \log s}{s}\,ds. \tag{$**$}
\end{align}
$$

Skipping some of the details,

$$
\int_{1/\lambda}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-s}}{s}\,ds \sim \int_{1/\lambda}^{1} \frac{e^{-s}}{s}\,ds \sim \int_{1/\lambda}^{1} \frac{1}{s}\,ds = \log \lambda
$$

and

$$
\int_{1/\lambda}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-s} \log s}{s}\,ds \sim \int_{1/\lambda}^{1} \frac{e^{-s} \log s}{s}\,ds \sim \int_{1/\lambda}^{1} \frac{\log s}{s}\,ds = - \frac{(\log \lambda)^2}{2}
$$

as $\lambda \to \infty$.

By substituting these into $(**)$ we get

$$
\int_1^\infty \frac{\log t}{t} x^t\,dt \sim \frac{(\log \lambda)^2}{2} = \frac{(-\log(-\log x))^2}{2} \sim \frac{(\log(1-x))^2}{2}
$$

and hence

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\log n}{n} x^n \sim \frac{(\log(1-x))^2}{2}
$$

as $x \to 1^-$ by $(*)$.

Comment: This is a big help to me, thank you.  I see that the lemma in the linked pdf is from your own notes.  Is there somewhere I can go for a reference of this theorem?  Was it part of your own research?  I just want to make sure I give proper attribution.

Comment: My formula is a slight generalization of the [integral test for convergence of a series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence). The [Euler-Maclaurin formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula) would be its big brother, which you could use to obtain better estimates for your sum (and possibly a full asymptotic expansion). I proved it because I wanted a simple formula which worked for unimodal summands (note that the integral test for convergence assumes the summand is monotone).

Answer (score 3):

We have $\mathcal{L}(\log x)=-\frac{\gamma+\log(s)}{s}$, hence $\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{\log s}{s}\right) =-\left(\log(x)+\gamma\right)$. Additionally
$$ \mathcal{L}\left(\frac{\log x}{x}\right) = \frac{\pi^2}{12}+\frac{\left(\gamma+\log x\right)^2}{2},$$
hence a pretty good approximation is
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\log n}{n}\,x^n \sim \frac{(\gamma+\log(1-x))^2}{2}\quad \text{for }x\to 1^- $$
by just rephrasing Antonio Vargas' approach in terms of $\mathcal{L}/\mathcal{L}^{-1}$ and [Hardy Littlewood's tauberian theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy%E2%80%93Littlewood_tauberian_theorem).

Comment: Could you add some detail to your answer? I don't follow the argument. Also, I thought the tauberian theorem goes the other direction, namely asymptotics of $\sum a_n x^n$ as $x \to 1^-$ giving information about asymptotics of $\sum_{n \leq x} a_n$ as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: I also am interested in some additional details on the argument.  From my limited understanding of these approaches, reading the wikipedia page seems to suggest that indeed this theorem applies to the other direction.